# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Tags: python

Can't seem to find a straightforward answer to this question.  All I want to know is how to import the file I saved under my `\scripts` directory.

I added the path to `sys.path`...

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "C:\\my_Stuff\\data_science\\scripts")
```

I added a `__init__.py` file under my `\scripts` directory, which is the same directory where my `tree.py` file is.

I run...

```
import tree as tr
```

...but am still getting the error.

Comment: from `scripts import tree as tr`, I think. If you're importing from another file within `scripts`, you'll want `import script.tree as tr`.

Comment: Thanks.  Did that, and now I'm getting "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Comment: Does the exception raised from the referenced import? I guess no. The `import tree as tr` is *not* a relative import. I guess that the tree module has a relative import which throws this exception. Which python version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is probably late but the following is working for me.

Let's say i have "**my_file.py**" in the directory "**folder**":

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path\\to\\folder')

from my_file import ...
```

Hope this can help!